# Searching for an attribute by its value

Tags: c#, xml

I have following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Communication Id ="456">
    <Person> Ivan Ivanov </Person>
   <Describtion> 
          <Age> 16 </Age>
          <Place> Moscow </Place>
          <Key Name ="Language"> English </Key>
          <Key Name ="Profession"> Doctor </Key>
    </Describtion>  
  </Communication>

  <Communication Id ="1010">
    <Person> Petr Petrov </Person>
    <Describtion>
          <Age> 21 </Age>
          <Place> St.Peterburg </Place>
          <Key Name ="Language"> Français </Key>
          <Key Name ="Profession"> Ingeneer </Key>
    </Describtion>  
  </Communication>
</root>
```

There is a list of Key tags with attribute Name which has different value. This value determines which variable the value between tags will be written to. How can I write an algorithm for such a search?

Answer (score 0):

You can search like this.

```
xmlDoc.SelectNodes("root/Communication/Describtion/Key[@Name=\"Language\"][text()=\" English \"]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `XmlDocument`

```
public static string getNodeValue(XmlDocument xmldoc, string id, string key)
{
    return xmldoc.SelectSingleNode($"root/Communication[@Id='{id}']/Describtion/Key[@Name='{key}']")
                 .InnerText
                 .Trim();
}
```

Usage

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);
Console.WriteLine(getNodeValue(xmlDoc, "456", "Language"));
Console.WriteLine(getNodeValue(xmlDoc, "1010", "Language"));
```

Output

```
English
Français
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Medok_, you made everybody guess what you need in two languages. Please mark what worked for you as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used Xml Linq along with a dictionary and IEquatable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            reader.ReadLine();  //allow unicode characters
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            List<Person> people = doc.Descendants("Communication").Select(x => new Person()
            {
                id = (int)x.Attribute("Id"),
                name = (string)x.Element("Person"),
                age = (int)x.Descendants("Age").FirstOrDefault(),
                place = (string)x.Descendants("Place").FirstOrDefault(),
                language = ((string)x.Descendants("Key").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("Name") == "Language").FirstOrDefault()).Trim(),
                profession = ((string)x.Descendants("Key").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("Name") == "Profession").FirstOrDefault()).Trim()
            }).ToList();

            Dictionary<Person, List<Person>> dict = people
                .GroupBy(x => x, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            List<Person> results = dict[new Person() { language = "English", profession = "Doctor" }].ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string place { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string profession { get; set; }

        public Boolean Equals(Person other)
        {
            return
                (language == other.language) && (profession == other.profession);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (language + "^" + profession).GetHashCode() ;
        }

    }
}
```